# What happens to $f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^{\alpha}y}{x^4 + y^2}$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

As in the title I want to study what happens to $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$. Where $f: R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \} \rightarrow R$

$$f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^{\alpha}y}{x^4 + y^2} $$

A useful theorem I have been using is: Let $A \subset R^n, f:A\rightarrow R$ and let $x_0$ be an accumulation point of $A$.
Then the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = l \in \bar{R}$ if and only if $\forall{B} \subset A$ s.t. $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $B$ we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f|_B(x) = l$.

So if I restrict the function domain to all $ x = y$ I get

$$f(x,y) = \frac{|x|^{\alpha+1}}{x^{4} + x^2} = x^{\alpha -1}(1 + o(1))$$

this is 1 if $\alpha = 1$, $0$ if $\alpha> 1 $ and it goes to infinity if $\alpha <1$.

So now I know that for $\alpha <1$ the function does not converge in $R^2$ correct?

Then I notice that near $x = 0$ $$0 \le |f(x,y)| \le \frac{||(x,y)||^{1+\alpha}}{x^4+y^4} \le \frac{1}{c} ||(x,y)||^{\alpha -3}$$
by an euclidean distance inequality so the function converges for $\alpha>3$.

But what happens for $1 \le \alpha \le 3 $?

Comment: I suspect that your approach is weak. For $\alpha=2$, the function converges to zero in an elementary way.

Comment: @Siminore thank you, yes now I see that. but still all other values between 1 and 3 included remain.

Comment: The right column shows several near duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that the limit is equal to zero, if $\alpha>2$, and does not exist, if $\alpha\le2$.

Assume first that $\alpha>2$. We can then use the AM-GM inequality, $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}$, valid for all positive numbers $a,b$,  to give the denominator a lower bound
$$
x^4+y^2\ge 2\sqrt{x^4y^2}=2x^2|y|.
$$
Using this we get
$$
|f(x,y)|\le\frac{|x|^\alpha|y|}{2x^2|y|}=\frac12|x|^{\alpha-2}.
$$
This upper bound $\to 0$ whenever $\alpha>2$, so the sandwich principle gives our claim in this case.

The assume that $\alpha\le2$. Consider the case where we approach the origin along various curves parametrized by $x=t, y=kt^2$, where $k>0$ is some constant. Along such a curve we get
$$
|f(t,kt^2)|=\frac{k\cdot|t|^{\alpha+2}}{(1+k^2)t^4}=\frac{|k|}{1+k^2}|t|^{\alpha-2}.
$$
If $\alpha<2$, this grows without upper bound, when $t\to0$. If $\alpha=2$, then this is a constant that changes as the value of $k$ changes. In both cases we can conclude that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Comment: Small note: In the last paragraph, "with upper bound" should probably be "without upper bound".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. could I ask you to explain the parametrization approach to finding limits, I have never seen it before and thus remain not fully convinced. Maybe a quick example to show it works generally :). Thanks again

Comment: @Monolite: The use of parametrized curves is only for the purposes of showing that a limit does not exist. If we approach the point of interest along different curves, then if the function has a limit there, then the restriction of the function to those curves should have the SAME limit. If various curves give no limit at all, or distinct limits, then the function cannot have a limit. This is an extension of the single variable technique of checking left and right limits at the point. Except this time we can approach the point along infinitely many curves, not just from below or above.